# Need help formatting a string output

Tags: c++

```
vector<data> getList = readContent();
string output = "";
ostringstream conv;
istringstream is;

output += "s: 200 OK\nThe list of records in the book:\n";

for(int j = 0; j < getList.size(); j++)
{
 conv << getList[j].record;

 output += conv.str();
 output += "     ";
 output += getList[j].fName;
 output += " ";
 output += getList[j].lName;
 output += "     ";
 output += getList[j].phoneNum;
 output += "   \n";

 conv.str("");
}

send(s, (char *)output.c_str(), strlen((char *)output.c_str()), 0);
```

readContent() returns a vector containing all the data that is read from a file.
This is printing everything that is in the vector.  However, I cannot figure out how to format the each thing in a vector in a specific way:

**record** starts 0 spaces from left side
**fName** starts 10 spaces from left side
**lName** starts right after a space that is after fName
**phoneNum** starts 30 spaces from left side

*all in 1 line.*  Here is a picture example (can't format on this thread editor...)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlJ41.png

I understand this can be done using setw(), but thats only when you're directly outputting by using the << operators (or am I wrong?).  It needs to be in a form of a string so I can send it to the client through a socket.

Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: Your images has errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#include <iomanip>` and use all of its tools.

You can build a `string` in the same way you'd output with `cout` if you `#include <sstream>` and use `stringstreams`

```
stringstream ss;
ss << //do stuff the same way you'd cout
return ss.str(); //or whatever you need to do with the built string
```

Comment: Oh okay, I'll try that and come back with a result.